# Compiled error when trying to use global constants : "undefined symbols for architecture i386"

Tags: objective-c, ios7, reference, xcode5, constants

I am a beginner in iOs development. I search severals hours and try many things but still not work. I am totally lonely.

I have a project with 2 storyboards (iPhone + iPad) and 3 pairs of files .h/.m (AppDelgate, MasterViewController, DetailViewController).

I download all I need in my AppDelegate.m and would like to store results in global constants declared in my AppDelegate.h like this :

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
//javascript & css files
extern NSData *const JQUERY_FILE;
extern NSData *const JQUERYUI_FILE;
extern NSData *const JQUERY_MOBILE_FILE;
extern NSData *const JQUERY_MOBILE_CSS_FILE;
extern NSData *const APPLICATION_FILE;
extern NSData *const FEED_FILE;
@end
```

And in AppDelegate.m :

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
@implementation AppDelegate
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"];
  NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Library/Application Support/jquery.js", NSHomeDirectory()];
  NSData *const JQUERY_FILE = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
  [JQUERY_FILE writeToFile:path options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error];
 …
```

I import AppDelegate.h in my 2 others files .m : MasterViewController.m & DetailViewController.m

I have a compiled error when I try to build my project.

```
Ld /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Test_JSON_V2-avjvupkzamqjszcpvufoeqrdbjin/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Test_JSON_V2.app/Test_JSON_V2 normal i386
cd /Users/Karine/Projects/Test_JSON_V2/IOS-ManualJson
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=7.1
export        PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk -L/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Test_JSON_V2-avjvupkzamqjszcpvufoeqrdbjin/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Test_JSON_V2-avjvupkzamqjszcpvufoeqrdbjin/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Test_JSON_V2-avjvupkzamqjszcpvufoeqrdbjin/Build/Intermediates/Test_JSON_V2.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Test_JSON_V2.build/Objects-normal/i386/Test_JSON_V2.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=7.1 -framework CoreGraphics -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Test_JSON_V2-avjvupkzamqjszcpvufoeqrdbjin/Build/Intermediates/Test_JSON_V2.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Test_JSON_V2.build/Objects-normal/i386/Test_JSON_V2_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Test_JSON_V2-avjvupkzamqjszcpvufoeqrdbjin/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Test_JSON_V2.app/Test_JSON_V2

  Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
 "_APPLICATION_FILE", referenced from:
     -[MasterViewController viewDidLoad] in MasterViewController.o
 "_JQUERYUI_FILE", referenced from:
  -[DetailViewController webViewDidFinishLoad:] in DetailViewController.o
 "_JQUERY_FILE", referenced from:
     -[DetailViewController webViewDidFinishLoad:] in DetailViewController.o
 "_JQUERY_MOBILE_CSS_FILE", referenced from:
     -[DetailViewController webViewDidFinishLoad:] in DetailViewController.o
 "_JQUERY_MOBILE_FILE", referenced from:
     -[DetailViewController webViewDidFinishLoad:] in DetailViewController.o
 ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I would like to give you a printScreen but I can't because I'm too beginner :/

I check my 3 m files are in Target Membership in the file editor, and in the Compile Sources (in Build phases)
I try to:

- create a .h file that contains all constants and add it by doing Editor -> Add build phase -> Add copy headers build phase
- add AppDelegate.h in Link Binary With Libraries
- add a new User Header Search Paths in Build Settings

When I use and click on a global constant in MasterViewController or DetailViewController, the help window at right shows that it is declared in the right file.

Do you have any idea please ?
Thanks in advance.

---

Edit 22/07/2014

I try in a simple application to define & use global constants. It works when :

- declaration in the header is outside of the block @interface
- assignment in the m file is outside of the block @implementation

But I do not know how I can add my code outside the @implementation of my AppDelegate.m file.  I'm going to investigate this point.

Comment: You need a `.m` file that contains a *non extern* definition of all the variables that you've declared in the `.h` file. By using extern you're saying that the definition of the variable will be found elsewhere, but wherever that definition is, it's not linked into the app

Comment: Hello @Petesh. My constants are assigned in my `AppDelegate.m` and this file is adding to the compile sources. If I delete in .m file `NSData *const JQUERY_FILE = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];` by `JQUERY_FILE = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];` I have an error : read-only variable is not assignable.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to access a property within AppDelegate from another UIViewController this may help:

in **AppDelegate.h** you would declare a property

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSData *someData;
```

Generate the data in your **AppDelagate.m**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

 [self generateData];
 //any other code
 }

-(void) generateData{
//Populate your property
_someData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
}
```

Then to access the data from another UIView controller you can do this:

**SomeViewController.m**

```
NSData * localSomeData = [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] someData];
```

Comment: Thanks for response but I prefer to work with global constants instead of using a method. Your solution leads my problem astray. My goal is using global constants for reducing my code. Files are downloaded and saved on device but I do not want to search every time I need them

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with the following code. I can not use constants in my case because the value is set at runtime. I did not found any solution for resolving this. So I choose global variables.

In AppDelegate.h :

```
// GLOBAL VARIABLES
// javascript & css files
extern NSData *JQUERY_FILE;
extern NSData *JQUERYUI_FILE;
extern NSData *JQUERY_MOBILE_FILE;
extern NSData *JQUERY_MOBILE_CSS_FILE;
// json files
extern NSData *APPLICATION_FILE;
extern NSData *FEED_FILE;
// END GLOBAL VARIABLES

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@end
```

In AppDelegate.m :

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

NSData *JQUERY_FILE;
NSData *JQUERYUI_FILE;
NSData *JQUERY_MOBILE_FILE;
NSData *JQUERY_MOBILE_CSS_FILE;
NSData *APPLICATION_FILE;
NSData *FEED_FILE;

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
// Override point for customization after application launch.
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    UISplitViewController *splitViewController = (UISplitViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject];
    splitViewController.delegate = (id)navigationController.topViewController;
}

#pragma Download & save javascript & css files
NSLog(@"%@", NSHomeDirectory());

NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];

// Get the Bundle identifier for creating dynamic path for storing all files
NSString *bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];
// NSHomeDirectory returns the application's sandbox directory
// FileManager is using for creating the Application Support Folder
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSURL *appliSupportDir = [fileManager URLForDirectory:NSApplicationSupportDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask appropriateForURL:nil create:YES error:&error];
[appliSupportDir URLByAppendingPathComponent:bundle isDirectory:YES];

// Get jquery files in network
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"];
NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Library/Application Support/jquery.js", NSHomeDirectory()];
//JQUERY_FILE = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
JQUERY_FILE = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
[[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url] writeToFile:path options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error];

url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.min.js"];
path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Library/Application Support/jqueryUI.js", NSHomeDirectory()];
//JQUERYUI_FILE = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
JQUERYUI_FILE = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
[[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url] writeToFile:path options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error];

url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.3/jquery.mobile.min.js"];
path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Library/Application Support/jqueryMobile.js", NSHomeDirectory()];
//JQUERY_MOBILE_FILE = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
JQUERY_MOBILE_FILE = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
[[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url] writeToFile:path options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error];

url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.3/jquery.mobile.min.css"];
path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Library/Application Support/jqueryMobileCSS.css", NSHomeDirectory()];
//JQUERY_MOBILE_CSS_FILE = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
JQUERY_MOBILE_CSS_FILE = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
[[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url] writeToFile:path options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error];


#pragma Download & save Json Files
// Read Json file in network. WARNING : ID EN DUR !!
// Get Application File
url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://testapp.visionit.lan:8087/api/application/79e45c6e-9e87-4576-b028-609ae2902f00"];
path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Library/Application Support/myApplication.json", NSHomeDirectory()];
APPLICATION_FILE = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
[APPLICATION_FILE writeToFile:path options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error];
// Get Feed File
url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://testapp.visionit.lan:8087/api/feed/79e45c6e-9e87-4576-b028-609ae2902f00"];
path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Library/Application Support/myFeed.json", NSHomeDirectory()];
FEED_FILE = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
[FEED_FILE writeToFile:path options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error];


return YES;
}
```

Next, import the AppDelegate.h where you want to use global variables.

It works for me.
Hope it helps